# How to use ranged-based for loops with std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++11, for-loop

Can you use a C++11 ranged-based for loop with an std::weak_ptr instead of using a for_each with lambda, as seen below?

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<IObservable>> observers;

std::for_each(this->observers.cbegin(), this->observers.cend(),
[](const std::weak_ptr<IObservable>& _o)
{
    auto observer = _o.lock();
    if (observer)
    {
       observer->Notify()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why not. Are you getting any error messages?

this:

```
for( const auto& o: observers ) {
  if( auto observer = o.lock() ) {
    observer->Notify();
  }
}
```

should work ok... :D

Comment: I mistakenly avoided lock() in my ranged-based for loop implementation as I didn't understand how weak_ptr's worked until now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) most likely translates to:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return f;
}
```

and that [*range-based for loops*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) translates to:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
    __end = end_expr; 
    __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

You can see just few differences:

- the latter does not allow iterators different from `begin()` and `end()`
- the former returns the unary function

But in the overall picture, using it in place of your `std::for_each`, in you situation, would work perfectly fine.

And here's how:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<IObservable>> observers;

for (const auto& _o) {
    auto observer = _o.lock();
    if (observer)
       observer->Notify();
}
```

Comment: C++17 changes the definition of the range-based for loop to allow `begin()` and `end()` to return different types.